# My SparkJava resource server gets 403 errors when trying to validate access tokens

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spark-java

I want to set up a very basic REST API using Spark-java, which just checks an access token obtained from my own authorisation server. It creates a GET request to the authorisation server's `/oauth/authorize` endpoint followed by `?token=$ACCESS_TOKEN`.

Whenever I try this, I get diverted to the `/error` endpoint and a 403 error.

Here's my API class:

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import spark.utils.StringUtils;

import java.io.IOException;

import static spark.Spark.*;

public class SampleAPI {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("SampleAPI");

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Run on port 9782
    port(9782);
    // Just returns "Hello there" to the client's console
    before((preRequest, preResponse) -> {

      System.out.println("Getting token from request");
      final String authHeader = preRequest.headers("Authorization");
      //todo validate token, don't just accept it because it's not null/empty
      if(StringUtils.isEmpty(authHeader) || !isAuthenticated(authHeader)){
        halt(401, "Access not authorised");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Token = " + authHeader);
      }
    });
    get("/", (res, req) -> "Hello there");
  }

  private static boolean isAuthenticated(final String authHeader) {
    String url = "http://localhost:9780/oauth/authorize";
    //"Bearer " is before the actual token in authHeader, so we need to extract the token itself as a substring
    String token = authHeader.substring(7);
    HttpGet getAuthRequest = new HttpGet(url + "?token=" + token);
    getAuthRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", ContentType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED.getMimeType());
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createMinimal();
    try {
      CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getAuthRequest);
      int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
      System.out.println("Status code " + statusCode + " returned for access token " + authHeader);
      return statusCode == 200;
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
      System.out.println("Exception when trying to validate access token " + ioException);
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

The `System.out.println` statements are just for debugging.

Here's my authorisation server's WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class:

```
    package main.config;
    
    import main.service.ClientAppDetailsService;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.factory.PasswordEncoderFactories;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
    
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
      @Autowired
      private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
      @Override
      @Bean
      public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        //returns AuthenticationManager from the superclass for authenticating users
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
      }
    
      @Bean
      public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
      }
    
      @Override
      public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        //Allow for DB access without any credentials
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/h2-console/**");
      }
    
      @Override
      protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //configures user details, and uses the custom UserDetailsService to check user credentials
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
      }
    
      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    
        //disable CORS and CSRF protection for Postman testing
        http.cors().disable().anonymous().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        http.csrf().disable();
      }
    }
```

And here's my authorisation server's `application.properties`:

```
server.port=9780

#in-memory database, will get populated using data.sql
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=syst3m
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
#adds to existing DB instead of tearing it down and re-populating it every time the app is started
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false
```

What have I done wrong? Do I need to specify my API as a resource server using Spring Security? Do I need to add it to the authorisation server's `application.properties`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Spring as a security framework then the most common option is to configure it as a resource server. Here is a [getting started tutorial](https://curity.io/resources/learn/spring-boot-api/). The API will then never get redirected.

With Spark another option is to just provide a basic filter that uses a JWT validation library, such as jose4j. This tends to provide better control over error responses and gives you better visibility over what is going on. See [this Kotlin example](https://curity.io/resources/learn/kotlin-api/), which will be easy enough to translate to Java.